# The image I upload to my Laravel API from Postman is not saved in the folder

Tags: php, laravel, api, heroku, postman

When trying to upload an image from Postman the image I send is not saved in my API folder on Heroku. But it is stored somewhere, because when I use `asset()` and open that link shows me the image correctly.

The route is for the creation of a product, and the image corresponds to it:

Route:

```
Route::post('product/new','ProductController@store');
```

In my controller:

```
    $product = new Product;
    $product->name = $request->input('name');
        //Other staff

    if($request->file('image')){

    $path = Storage::disk('public')->put('uploads/images/products',$request->file('image'));
   // $product->image = $path;
    $product->image = asset($path);
}
```

And the Postman config:

[image]

I already tried to configure the content type headers with `x-www-form-urlencoded`, with Content type `multipart/form-data` and without any Content type, and none of them worked.

The result I'm getting is:

```
{
"id": 1,
"name": "test1",
//staff
"image": "http://{{my_API_domain}}/uploads/images/products/Mz9liaazzCOTwt8CdEWK0My6w3l2GWzR1ERDncCV.png",
}
```

If I enter to `http://{{my_API_domain}}/uploads/images/products/Mz9liaazzCOTwt8CdEWK0My6w3l2GWzR1ERDncCV.png` from the browser, that link shows me the image well, but if I go to check there:`public/uploads/images/products/`  there are no saved images, have no idea where this images are getting stored.

Also, I did run `php artisan storage:link` and the symbolic link folder storage was created fine in `public/`, but just have the `.gitignore` inside and in my `config/filesystem.php` I change the `'public' => [ 'root' => storage_path('app/public'),]`, 
to 
`'public' => [ 'root' => public_path(),]`

My file structure:

[image]

Comment: Do you have a symbolink set up between `public/storage` and `storage/app/public`? Is it not perhaps in your `storage/app/public` folder?

Comment: I did run 'php artisan storage:link' and the folder storage was created fine in public/, but just have the .gitignore inside and in my config/filesystem.php I change the  'public' => [ 'root' => storage_path('app/public'),], to 'root' => public_path(),

Comment: I just made an edit and upload my folder structure, thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure where your file is being stored, but the bigger problem is that you're saving files to the local filesystem in the first place. Even if you figure out where the files are going this won't work as expected.

Heroku's filesystem [is ephemeral](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem). Any changes you make to it will be lost the next time your dyno restarts. This [happens frequently](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#automatic-dyno-restarts) (at least once per day). Heroku [recommends](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3) storing uploaded files on a third-party service like Amazon S3.

Luckily for you, Laravel [supports this out of the box](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/filesystem#driver-prerequisites):

- Add `league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3 ~1.0` to your dependencies
- Create an S3 bucket
- Configure Laravel to use the bucket in `config/filesystems.php`

You don't need to make any changes to your uploading code. Files should now be automatically saved to your S3 bucket, letting them survive dyno cycling and new deployments.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I figured it would be a problem with heroku, but I have a question, I was thinking of using heroku only for the development stage, but for the production stage if I was thinking of moving somewhere else, in that case I should be able to have configured the upload of files as the normal way (in the API folder) rigth??

Comment: Chris first of all THANK YOU, I was reading about your explanation, and I see that you are absolutely right, in fact I saw that you had answered a similar question before, I found this guide https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-upload-files-to-amazon-s3-using-laravel and I will follow it, but I still have the doubt of the previous comment, if I change my platform (heroku) will I still be able to use aws as storage? does it affect anything to do it this way with a third party? Need your advice ahah

Comment: @WilsonGuerrero, you should definitely use S3 for file storage on other platforms. You just _have to_ do it on Heroku :-).

Answer (score 0):

```
php artisan storage:link
```

becomes public/storage/
symlink to storage/app/public

your image should be at

```
"http://{{my_API_domain}}/storage/uploads/images/products/Mz9liaazzCOTwt8CdEWK0My6w3l2GWzR1ERDncCV.png"
```